# Header Location - return url in post - is it safe?

Tags: php

I have something like this (short version):
index.php:

```
<?PHP
echo "<form action='process_form.php?action=do_something' method='post'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='return_url' value='index.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']."'>";
?>
```

and now in process_form.php I have processed that form and at the end of it I put this:

```
<?PHP
$return_url = $_POST['return_url'];
header ("location: $return_url");
die();
?>
```

My question is - am I doing it right? Is it right way of processing POST forms data and redirecting back? Thing is that my return url can be anything, but I want users be redirected exactly to where they submitted that form.

Is there some security concern I should pay special attention to?
Thanks

Comment: I think this will not make much impact, as redirect url whether you specify via hidden field or you directly use it in process_form.php is equally vulnerable as well as equally safe, there is no much difference in these two.

Comment: Be sure to never use `urldecode($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` on your output.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

**index.php**

```
<form action="process_form.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_something" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**process_form.php**

```
<?php
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
?>
```

Comment: I wish I had some more Karma on this website so I could upvote all your helpful anwers! But it won't let me. I will try again when I gain some more points. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using `$_POST` anywhere in your code without filtering has a potential to cause unwanted behaviour; in your case, you should be aware of [response splitting attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_response_splitting).

The good news is that since PHP 5.1.2 it's no longer possible to unknowingly set multiple headers in a single header() call.

That said, you could still check out the various [input filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) that typically ship with PHP - e.g. `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem. A hacker would gain nothing by tinkering with the POST variable. He's just messing with the HTTP response he himself is going to get. Since the request is a POST, a  caching server would not save the response. Response splitting is not a potential attack vector here.

What you're doing is correct. If instead of $_POST, you were to redirect off a $_SESSION variable, then there would be multiple vulnerabilities.